# JBoss AS 7 JMX Console

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, mbeans, jboss7.x

I spent some time checking out [JBoss AS7](http://www.jboss.org/as7.html) today. I am impressed with what I have seen so far but I noticed that good ol' JMX-Console no longer exist.

1. Does anyone know why it was left out?
2. I understand that I can connect through JConsole, MC4J etc. but is there an alternative that would provide web based access to the deployed MBeans?

Comment: I was wondering the same. Connecting through JConsole is often not possible in enterprise environments due to firewall constraints (RMI isn't ideal in these situation to say the least). JBoss its simple web based JMX console has proven to be a real lifesaver in these situations.

Comment: Totally agree. Besides, our production support team use direct HTTP links to specific MBeans for particular type of issues.  To move to AS7, we either have to find an alternative or re-train them for specific tasks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to this thread (see below), there will be no such thing. Server management will be achieved in another way - via JBoss native interfaces. There will be, however, a compatibility layer exposing JBoss services through JMX.

http://community.jboss.org/thread/169408

Comment: Thanks Michal for digging this thread...I think it's a mistake not to provide JMX console that's been helpful to many of us for the longest time.

Comment: This answer should probably be edited since JBoss 7 now ships with a JMX console out of the box.

Comment: Is there a way to expose custom application specific MBeans through JBoss Admin console?

Answer (score 17):

JBoss AS 7 will have many ways to be managed.
At least these are those I know of:

1. Programatical:

   - CLI - bash-like command-line tool,
   - Java API - a Java JAR with remoting, you simply call methods.
   - REST-like API - you send commands over HTTP.

     - JBoss AS 7 Management API docs:
       https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Management+API+reference
2. User Interface:

   - Administration Console, see http://localhost:9990/console (by default)
   - RHQ project

     - See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Management+Clients

Current location of emerging JBoss AS 7 Documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Documentation

Answer (score 12):

JBoss AS7 now integrates with jconsole.  So you can use jconsole as a JMX client to AS7.  It also uses a jconsole add-on to provide CLI GUI in your jconsole instance.

See:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJconsoleToConnectToJMXOnAS7

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingCLIGUIWithJconsoleOnJBossAS7

Answer (score 1):

There are various web based jmx browsers that can be used inside any web container. I tend to perfect using the jconsole or jrockit mission control as you get extra this like graphing of values

In the past jboss used it's own mbean server, so you could only use jboss specific jmx tools, but now jboss-as, uses the mbean server of the jvm so any tool that works with your jvm of choice can be used for inspecting jboss-as 7