# server.xml equivalent in JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss, migration, jboss7.x, upgrade

I am trying to run my application in jboss 7 from jboss 4. In jboss 4 we changed server.xml to configure keystoreFile and keystorePass etc. Can any one help me where to make these changes in jboss7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server.xml equivalent in Jboss 7 is a standalone/configuration/standalone.xml for a standalone installation and domain.xml for a domain aware one.

I'm not sure where those options are or how you're supposed to configure it in Jboss 7, but start with standalone.xml file first.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the file `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="default-host">
    <connector name="http" scheme="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
       <alias name="localhost" />
       <alias name="example.com" />
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Replace thew `connector` tag with following one:

```
<connector name="https" scheme="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" secure =”true” socket-   binding="https" ssl=”your certificate name”/>
```

Comment: where do i have to put the certs? any special place?

Comment: @Joerg 
you have to set the system property javax.net.ssl.trustStore in standalone.xml or domain.xml: 
    <system-properties> <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore" value="/path/to/truststore.jks"/> </system-properties>    

https://community.jboss.org/thread/172052

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid touching the config XMLs yourself.
Rather let it up to **domain controller** and **host controller**,
and configure your server through the means mentioned here:
[JBoss AS 7 JMX Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702674/jboss-7-jmx-console/6789727#6789727)

Update:

- For manual configuration, try the [Web UI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-WebManagementInterface) - `http://localhost:9990/`.
- For automated configuration, try [CLI scripts](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-RunningtheCLI).
- To develop and debug CLI commands, try `jboss-cli.sh --gui`.

But if you really must, it's in `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" ...>
```

The schema is here: http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-as-web_1_2.xsd
([or later versions](http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/)).

Answer (score 1):

Recommended way to change the AS 7 model is anyway by means of the Command Line Interface.
For example, you can set the socket binding port of the HTTP port to 8090 with :

/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=http:write-attribute(name="port", value="8090")

Answer (score 0):

JBoss EAP 7 uses the [Undertow](http://undertow.io/) web server and configures it via the `undertow` subsystem (which replaces the `web` subsystem used in previous versions). SSL/TLS setup using the CLI is described in [Setting up an SSL/TLS for Applications](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/how_to_configure_server_security/index#setting_up_an_ssl_tls_for_applications). If you would like to directly modify the `standalone.xml` file, the instructions can be translated to:

1. *Add and configure an HTTPS security realm.* - under `/server/management/security-realms` add an HTTPS `security-realm` element, for example

   ```
   <security-realm name="HTTPSRealm">
     <server-identities>
         <ssl>
             <keystore path="/path/to/your/keystore/myKeystore.jks"
                       keystore-password="myKeystorePassword"
                       alias="mySSLKeyPairAlias"
                       key-password="mySSLKeyPairPassword" />
         </ssl>
     </server-identities>
   </security-realm>
   ```
2. *Update the undertow subsystem to use the HTTPS security realm.* - under `/server/profile` find the Undertow subsystem element (e.g. `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">`). It has a `server` child element to which you add an `https-listener` element referencing your `HTTPSRealm` created in step 1 above, for example

   ```
   <https-listener name="default-ssl" socket-binding="https" security-realm="HTTPSRealm" />
   ```

More details can be found at these related links:

- [Security Realms](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Security+Realms)
- Security Realm [Detailed Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Detailed+Configuration)
- [https-listener Attributes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/configuration_guide/#https_listener_attributes)