# JBoss 7 application, start/stop from ui?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I am running an application on a Jboss 6 server and using mbeans to start/stop my app without redeploying/restarting server. I was testing on JBoss 7 and saw that there were no mbean support.

How do I create that functionality now? I've yet to find anything on this.

Comment: Mayby answers in that question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702674/jboss-7-jmx-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There **is** MBean support.

In what area do you experience problems: when deploying MBeans or accessing them, ...?

Comment: There is? I get an error when deploying the application. WstxParsingException: "Received event DTD, instead of START_ELEMENT or END_ELEMENT." the problem is in my jboss-service.xml where I define the bean.

Comment: Ok, I removed the custom xml and tested it in the server config instead. Now I can deploy. But how do I reach the mbean interface without jxm-console?

Comment: See this: http://community.jboss.org/thread/169408 which is also present in the thread Lukasz mentioned.
In short: Use JConsole.

Comment: Yes, thanks. JConsole was just what I was looking for. Still getting the parse error obviously. But it's a start.

Comment: I'm marking this as answer because it solved the original question. MBeans could be reached with JConsole. Strange this isn't at least recommended in the AS7 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime (2015), there is a portation of the AS5 jmx-console, which can be deployed to AS7 and WildFly.
See https://github.com/wildfly-extras/jmx-console