# Jboss Performance Metrics

Tags: jboss, console, jboss7.x, jboss5.x, metrics

With Jboss 4 and 5 I could access the following metrics through the web-console (see sample screenshot).  Is this information still available in Jboss 7?  If so, where?

- free Memory
- total Memory
- max Memory
- max Threads
- min Spare Threads
- max Spare Threads
- current Thread Count
- current Thread Busy
- max Processing Time
- processing Time
- request Count
- error Count
- bytes Received
- bytes Sent

[image: example console]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702674/jboss-as-7-jmx-console